# Setting window/picture title

Tags: matlab, title, image

I have:

```
img = imread('pic.jpg','jpg');
r = img(:,:,1);
g = img(:,:,2);
b = img(:,:,3);

figure, imshow(r);
figure, imshow(g);
figure, imshow(b);
```

How to set title over each picture?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to change the `Name`-property of the figure window.

```
img = imread('pic.jpg','jpg');
r = img(:,:,1);
g = img(:,:,2);
b = img(:,:,3);

figure('Name','this is the red channel'), imshow(r);
figure('Name','this is the green channel','NumberTitle','off'), imshow(g);
title(gca,'you can also place a title like this')    

fh = figure; imshow(b);
set(fh,'Name','this is the blue channel')
```

Also, if you call `imshow(g,[])`, it will auto-scale the image to min/max.

Comment: Nice! This is title of window:). Can you also tell me how to change Text over picture (in window)?

Comment: ??? Error using ==> title at 29
Incorrect number of input arguments

Error in ==> title at 23
  h = title(gca,varargin{:});     This is when i try using title('gca','you can also place a title like this')

Comment: @Miko Kronn: fixed the error. `gca` should not be in quotes. Btw: Please don't forget to accept an answer if it was helpful.