# How to change the window title of a MATLAB plotting figure?

Tags: matlab, title, plot

I have created a [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) plotting with the `plot()` function. How do I change the window title of the generated figure of the plotting?

My MATLAB m-file which I'm working on:

```
hold on

x = [0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 1; 1.2; 1.4; 1.6; 1.8; 2; 2.2; 2.4; 2.6; 2.8; 3; 3.2; 3.4; 3.6; 3.8; 4; 4.2; 4.4; 4.6; 4.8; 5; 5.2; 5.4; 5.6; 5.8; 6; 6.2; 6.4; 6.6; 6.8; 7; 7.2; 7.4; 7.6; 7.8; 8; 8.2; 8.4; 8.6; 8.8; 9; 9.2; 9.4; 9.6; 9.8; 10; 10.2; 10.4; 10.6; 10.8; 11; 11.2; 11.4; 11.6; 11.8; 12; 12.2; 12.4; 12.6; 12.8; 13; 13.2; 13.4; 13.6; 13.8; 14; 14.2; 14.4; 14.6; 14.8; 15; 15.2; 15.4; 15.6; 15.8; 16; 16.2; 16.4; 16.6; 16.8; 17; 17.2; 17.4; 17.6; 17.8; 18; 18.2; 18.4; 18.6; 18.8];
y = [0; 0.198669; 0.389418; 0.564642; 0.717356; 0.841471; 0.932039; 0.98545; 0.999574; 0.973848; 0.909297; 0.808496; 0.675463; 0.515501; 0.334988; 0.14112; -0.0583741; -0.255541; -0.44252; -0.611858; -0.756802; -0.871576; -0.951602; -0.993691; -0.996165; -0.958924; -0.883455; -0.772764; -0.631267; -0.464602; -0.279415; -0.0830894; 0.116549; 0.311541; 0.494113; 0.656987; 0.793668; 0.898708; 0.96792; 0.998543; 0.989358; 0.940731; 0.854599; 0.734397; 0.584917; 0.412118; 0.22289; 0.0247754; -0.174327; -0.366479; -0.544021; -0.699875; -0.827826; -0.922775; -0.980936; -0.99999; -0.979178; -0.919329; -0.822829; -0.693525; -0.536573; -0.358229; -0.165604; 0.033623; 0.23151; 0.420167; 0.592074; 0.740376; 0.859162; 0.943696; 0.990607; 0.998027; 0.965658; 0.894791; 0.788252; 0.650288; 0.486399; 0.303118; 0.107754; -0.0919069; -0.287903; -0.472422; -0.638107; -0.778352; -0.887567; -0.961397; -0.9969; -0.992659; -0.948844; -0.867202; -0.750987; -0.604833; -0.434566; -0.246974; -0.0495356];
plot(x, y, '--b');

x = [0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 1; 1.2; 1.4; 1.6; 1.8; 2; 2.2; 2.4; 2.6; 2.8; 3; 3.2; 3.4; 3.6; 3.8; 4; 4.2; 4.4; 4.6; 4.8; 5; 5.2; 5.4; 5.6; 5.8; 6; 6.2; 6.4; 6.6; 6.8; 7; 7.2; 7.4; 7.6; 7.8; 8; 8.2; 8.4; 8.6; 8.8; 9; 9.2; 9.4; 9.6; 9.8; 10; 10.2; 10.4; 10.6; 10.8; 11; 11.2; 11.4; 11.6; 11.8; 12; 12.2; 12.4; 12.6; 12.8; 13; 13.2; 13.4; 13.6; 13.8; 14; 14.2; 14.4; 14.6; 14.8; 15; 15.2; 15.4; 15.6; 15.8; 16; 16.2; 16.4; 16.6; 16.8; 17; 17.2; 17.4; 17.6; 17.8; 18; 18.2; 18.4; 18.6; 18.8];
y = [-1; -0.980133; -0.921324; -0.825918; -0.697718; -0.541836; -0.364485; -0.172736; 0.0257666; 0.223109; 0.411423; 0.583203; 0.731599; 0.850695; 0.935744; 0.983355; 0.991629; 0.960238; 0.890432; 0.784994; 0.648128; 0.48529; 0.302972; 0.108443; -0.0905427; -0.286052; -0.470289; -0.635911; -0.776314; -0.885901; -0.960303; -0.996554; -0.993208; -0.950399; -0.869833; -0.754723; -0.609658; -0.44042; -0.253757; -0.057111; 0.141679; 0.334688; 0.514221; 0.673121; 0.805052; 0.904756; 0.968256; 0.993023; 0.978068; 0.923987; 0.832937; 0.708548; 0.555778; 0.380717; 0.190346; -0.00774649; -0.205663; -0.395514; -0.56973; -0.721365; -0.844375; -0.933855; -0.986238; -0.999436; -0.972923; -0.907755; -0.806531; -0.673287; -0.513333; -0.333047; -0.139617; 0.0592467; 0.255615; 0.44166; 0.609964; 0.753818; 0.867487; 0.946439; 0.987526; 0.989111; 0.95113; 0.875097; 0.764044; 0.622398; 0.455806; 0.27091; 0.0750802; -0.123876; -0.318026; -0.499631; -0.66145; -0.797032; -0.900972; -0.969126; -0.998776];
plot(x, y, '-r');

hold off

title('My plot title');
xlabel('My x-axis title');
ylabel('My y-axis title');
```

Its output figure is:

[image: The figure which is generated by the code above.]

How do I change the window title of this plot?

What command do I add, and/or what modifications should I do to change it?

Comment: By the way: It may be more convenient to define `x` as `0:0.2:18.8` and `y` as `sin(x)`.

Comment: @Jonas: You are right, but in this case, the m-file is generated by a C++ code. The `sin()` function is used in C++ code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB: Setting window/picture title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990951/matlab-setting-window-picture-title)

Comment: in order to remove `Figure 1` check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10929129/3252535

Answer (score 84, accepted):

First you must create an empty figure with the following command.

```
figure('name','Title of the window here');
```

By doing this, the newly created figure becomes you active figure. Immediately after calling a `plot()` command, it will print your plotting onto this figure. So your window will have a title.

This is the code you must use:

```
figure('name','Title of the window here');

hold on

x = [0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 1; 1.2; 1.4; 1.6; 1.8; 2; 2.2; 2.4; 2.6; 2.8; 3; 3.2; 3.4; 3.6; 3.8; 4; 4.2; 4.4; 4.6; 4.8; 5; 5.2; 5.4; 5.6; 5.8; 6; 6.2; 6.4; 6.6; 6.8; 7; 7.2; 7.4; 7.6; 7.8; 8; 8.2; 8.4; 8.6; 8.8; 9; 9.2; 9.4; 9.6; 9.8; 10; 10.2; 10.4; 10.6; 10.8; 11; 11.2; 11.4; 11.6; 11.8; 12; 12.2; 12.4; 12.6; 12.8; 13; 13.2; 13.4; 13.6; 13.8; 14; 14.2; 14.4; 14.6; 14.8; 15; 15.2; 15.4; 15.6; 15.8; 16; 16.2; 16.4; 16.6; 16.8; 17; 17.2; 17.4; 17.6; 17.8; 18; 18.2; 18.4; 18.6; 18.8];
y = [0; 0.198669; 0.389418; 0.564642; 0.717356; 0.841471; 0.932039; 0.98545; 0.999574; 0.973848; 0.909297; 0.808496; 0.675463; 0.515501; 0.334988; 0.14112; -0.0583741; -0.255541; -0.44252; -0.611858; -0.756802; -0.871576; -0.951602; -0.993691; -0.996165; -0.958924; -0.883455; -0.772764; -0.631267; -0.464602; -0.279415; -0.0830894; 0.116549; 0.311541; 0.494113; 0.656987; 0.793668; 0.898708; 0.96792; 0.998543; 0.989358; 0.940731; 0.854599; 0.734397; 0.584917; 0.412118; 0.22289; 0.0247754; -0.174327; -0.366479; -0.544021; -0.699875; -0.827826; -0.922775; -0.980936; -0.99999; -0.979178; -0.919329; -0.822829; -0.693525; -0.536573; -0.358229; -0.165604; 0.033623; 0.23151; 0.420167; 0.592074; 0.740376; 0.859162; 0.943696; 0.990607; 0.998027; 0.965658; 0.894791; 0.788252; 0.650288; 0.486399; 0.303118; 0.107754; -0.0919069; -0.287903; -0.472422; -0.638107; -0.778352; -0.887567; -0.961397; -0.9969; -0.992659; -0.948844; -0.867202; -0.750987; -0.604833; -0.434566; -0.246974; -0.0495356];
plot(x, y, '--b');

x = [0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 1; 1.2; 1.4; 1.6; 1.8; 2; 2.2; 2.4; 2.6; 2.8; 3; 3.2; 3.4; 3.6; 3.8; 4; 4.2; 4.4; 4.6; 4.8; 5; 5.2; 5.4; 5.6; 5.8; 6; 6.2; 6.4; 6.6; 6.8; 7; 7.2; 7.4; 7.6; 7.8; 8; 8.2; 8.4; 8.6; 8.8; 9; 9.2; 9.4; 9.6; 9.8; 10; 10.2; 10.4; 10.6; 10.8; 11; 11.2; 11.4; 11.6; 11.8; 12; 12.2; 12.4; 12.6; 12.8; 13; 13.2; 13.4; 13.6; 13.8; 14; 14.2; 14.4; 14.6; 14.8; 15; 15.2; 15.4; 15.6; 15.8; 16; 16.2; 16.4; 16.6; 16.8; 17; 17.2; 17.4; 17.6; 17.8; 18; 18.2; 18.4; 18.6; 18.8];
y = [-1; -0.980133; -0.921324; -0.825918; -0.697718; -0.541836; -0.364485; -0.172736; 0.0257666; 0.223109; 0.411423; 0.583203; 0.731599; 0.850695; 0.935744; 0.983355; 0.991629; 0.960238; 0.890432; 0.784994; 0.648128; 0.48529; 0.302972; 0.108443; -0.0905427; -0.286052; -0.470289; -0.635911; -0.776314; -0.885901; -0.960303; -0.996554; -0.993208; -0.950399; -0.869833; -0.754723; -0.609658; -0.44042; -0.253757; -0.057111; 0.141679; 0.334688; 0.514221; 0.673121; 0.805052; 0.904756; 0.968256; 0.993023; 0.978068; 0.923987; 0.832937; 0.708548; 0.555778; 0.380717; 0.190346; -0.00774649; -0.205663; -0.395514; -0.56973; -0.721365; -0.844375; -0.933855; -0.986238; -0.999436; -0.972923; -0.907755; -0.806531; -0.673287; -0.513333; -0.333047; -0.139617; 0.0592467; 0.255615; 0.44166; 0.609964; 0.753818; 0.867487; 0.946439; 0.987526; 0.989111; 0.95113; 0.875097; 0.764044; 0.622398; 0.455806; 0.27091; 0.0750802; -0.123876; -0.318026; -0.499631; -0.66145; -0.797032; -0.900972; -0.969126; -0.998776];
plot(x, y, '-r');

hold off

title('My plot title');
xlabel('My x-axis title');
ylabel('My y-axis title');
```

Answer (score 43):

You need to set `figure` properties.

At the very beginning of the script, call

```
figure('name','something else')
```

Calling `figure` is a good thing, anyway, because without it, you always plot into the same window, and sometimes you may want to compare two windows side-by-side.

Alternatively, you can store the figure's handle by calling

```
figH = figure;
```

so that you can later change the figure properties to your liking (the `'numberTitle'` property setting eliminates the "figure X" text)

```
set(figH,'Name','something else','NumberTitle','off')
```

Have a look at the [figure properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html) in the MATLAB documentation to see what else you can change if you want.

Comment: If I define two different figures by the `figure()`, in which figure my plotting will be drawn when I call `plot()`?

Comment: @hkBattousai: in the currently active one (as identified by the command `gcf` which returns the handle to the current figure). Calling `figure` will make the just created figure active, so unless you click really fast on another figure, plot will plot in the right place.

Answer (score 21):

It can also be done this way:

```
figure(xx);
set(gcf, 'name', 'Name goes here')
```

`gcf` gets the current figure handle.

Comment: or change `gcf` into `get(groot, 'Children')` to set all the firgure

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to include that your code script (as advised by others above), then simply you may do the following after generating the figure window:

1. Go to "Edit" in the figure window
2. Go to "Figure Properties"
3. At the bottom, you can type the name you want in "Figure Name" field. You can uncheck "Show Figure Number".

That's all.

Good luck.