# Get rid of "Figure 1" in the title of the figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a figure that I want his name to be `Step 2 of 3: Simulation Plot Window`, but its name is: `figure 2: Step 2 of 3: Simulation Plot Window`.

How can I change his name to the name I want?

I don't know if it's necessary, but in the start of the code I wrote:

```
hFig = figure('Name','window 1','Visible','Off');
```

and Towards my code ends, I write:

```
hFig = figure('Name','Step 2 of 3: Simulation Plot Window','Menubar','none', 'Resize','off', ...
    'WindowStyle','modal', 'Position',[300 300 1150 600]);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Showing the number in the title is one of the properties of the figure.
By default it is set to `on`, unless you are using `GUIDE`.

Anyway, in order to remove it, use

```
set(gcf,'NumberTitle','off');
```

A better way would be to use the handle that you got from a call to the `figure` function:

```
hFig = figure('Name','window 1','Visible','Off');
set(hFig,'NumberTitle','off');
```

Also, (as @GuntherStruyf also mentioned), it is possible to do it in the call to the `figure` function itself:

```
hFig = figure('Name','window 1','Visible','Off','NumberTitle','off');
```

Comment: you can also immediately add it to the figure creation itself: `hFig = figure('Name','Step 2/3: ...','NumberTitle','off')`