# Change Title with Octave imshow()

Tags: octave, imshow

Octave imshow() will display the image but the title of the image as "Figure 1", How can I change the title.

Comment: Get rid of "Figure 1": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929020 Change window title: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684363 Both for MATLAB, but apparently works for Octave 5.1.0, too. I just tested it.

Comment: No, i am trying to edit the title of the image, not the title of the figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own title to a figure window's title bar by setting the Name property to the desired title and you can turn off the figure number by setting the NumberTitle property to 'off' as follows:

```
title ("imshow with random 100x100 matrix");
```

see document for [more](http://imageprocessplace.blogspot.com/search/label/GNU%20Octave)

Comment: Can we use this for octave, I think your answer is based on Matlab.

Comment: Are you trying to change figure title or img title?

Comment: I am trying to change the img title

Comment: its working fine in octave what error it is giving  see http://imageprocessplace.blogspot.com/search/label/GNU%20Octave

Comment: Thanks, your code  working, There are no errors.