# My plotted lines aren't appearing on my output figures

Tags: matlab, image-processing, title, matlab-figure, figure

so I'm processing a bunch of images at the one time, trying to display them all as figures with a series of plotted lines on each individual image as a result of the process. With some help I fixed the figure title issue, However the plotted lines are not appearing on my final figures, below is the code:

```
inputFolder = fullfile(pwd, 'BMPData');
filePattern = fullfile(inputFolder, '*.bmp');
%Get list of all Bmp Files in Folder
BmpFiles = dir(filePattern)

for i=1:length(BmpFiles)
    fname = BmpFiles(i).name;
    fullFileNameInput = fullfile(inputFolder,fname);
    A = imread(fullFileNameInput);

    %// Change
    AR=A(:,:,1);
    [rows, columns] = size(AR);
    y1 = 200;
    y2 = 315;
    row1 = AR(y1, :); % Extract this line of gray levels from the image.
    row2 = AR(y2, :);
    figure('name',fname),imshow(A), hold on; 
    plot([0, columns], [y1, y1], '.b'); 
    plot([0, columns], [y2, y2], '.m');
end
```

The reason I am doing this is because I want to mark 2 rows (200 and 315) on all my images and then do some statistical analysis on all the pixels in them rows for further processing techniques.

Comment: OK great.  That does it for one image.  Can we see more code?  Where is `fname` being set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684363/how-to-change-the-window-title-of-a-matlab-plotting-figure

Comment: @rayryeng Ive added in my function and for statement, please see above, thanks.

Comment: Um, you copy/pasted a version of my answer that was not meant as a drop-in replacement. You are bound to get horrible errors in the second last line. The line `fh(i) = figure, imshow(A)` looks like an error, too. I think the `,` should be a `;`. Is there a reason why you have these statements on the same line?

Comment: Yea my apologies Just trying to 100 things at the one time today, Final year uni is really taking its tole on me! i really appreciate the feedback though, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting `columns` undefined is due to [variable scope](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/01/16/nested-functions-and-variable-scope/).  When you define `columns` in `SegmentationNew`, `columns` is only available **within the lifetime of `SegmentationNew`** and only visible **within** `SegmentationNew`.  Once `SegmentationNew` completes, `column` is no longer defined.

I honestly [can't make heads or tails](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can%27t+make+heads+or+tails+of) of what `SegmentationNew` is doing, but from the looks of it, there is no good reason why you should call it.  All you need from it is `y1` and `y2`, which are defined as constants.  `columns` you can determine from the columns of the image.  I'm also going to borrow from the duplicate post that Martin J.H. has linked to make naming the figure window more elegant.

To add to this post, your original code was plotting just the points.  If you want to plot the lines as well, you need to remove the `.` characters from your plotting string for each call to `plot`.  Specifically, change `.b` and `.m` to `b` and `m` respectively.

As such, do this:

```
for i=1:length(BmpFiles)
    fname = BmpFiles(i).name;
    fullFileNameInput = fullfile(inputFolder,fname);
    A = imread(fullFileNameInput);

    %// Change
    columns = size(A,2);
    y1 = 200;
    y2 = 315;

    figure('name',fname); %// Change
    imshow(A); hold on;
    plot([0, columns], [y1, y1], 'b'); hold on; %// Change
    plot([0, columns], [y2, y2], 'm');
end
```

Comment: The figure titles are fine now however the plotted lines aren't appearing on them

Comment: I'm not sure what it is exactly that you're trying to plot.  That's why I said I didn't understand what `SegmentationNew` was.  BTW, reading code in a comments block gets pretty ugly when it's more than a couple of lines.  Suggest you add this edit to your post.

Comment: sorry Im new to this website, Ive made edits to the question and tried to explain better.

Comment: @SeánMcNeill - Do you want to plot a **line** or just points?  Your plot syntax at the end (`'.b, '.m'`) only plots single points.  If you want to draw lines, remove the `.` for each `plot` call.... so just `b` and `m`.